# Every commutative subring is contained in a maximal commutative subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring.  Let $A$ be a commutative subring of $R$.  Show that $A$ is contained in a maximal commutative subring of $R$.

I'd like to use Zorn's Lemma.

I'd like to start by proving that the family $F$ of commutative subrings of R that contain A is inductive.

In other words, every chain in $F$ (ordered by inclusion) has a maximal element.

But what is the connection between commutativity and this inductive property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Due to the comments of user119598 and 120579, the answer provided below may be incorrect (in some cases). If by "maximal commutative subring" the subring is not required to be a proper subset of $R$, then the original argument (below the dashed line) is indeed correct. However it seems standard to require that a maximal subring is required to be a proper subset, and for the rest of this edit I will be using this definition.

If $R$ is not commutative, then the original argument is again correct. In this case, the union of a chain of commutative subrings is commutative and hence can not be all of $R$.

If $R$ is commutative, then the argument is not correct as we can not guarantee the union is a proper subset as pointed out in the comments below. Actually, in this case the statement may be false. A maximal commutative subring is just a maximal subring of the commutative ring $R$. The abstract of the paper [Most Commutative Rings Have Maximal Subrings](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1005386712000910) by Azarang and Karamzadeh seems to indicate that there are commutative rings for which a maximal subring does not exist. Unfortunately my university does not have access to the journal and I have been unable to get my hands on the paper.

---

To show that every chain has a maximal element, given a chain you should be able to find (e.g. construct) the maximal element. Hint: If $R$ has a 1, this is similar to how one shows that every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal.

Once you have this candidate, you must show it satisfies the properties required: i.e. you must show it is commutative.

Comment: I'll take a guess and let my candidate be the union of the elements of my chain.

Comment: I solved it using this result: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Increasing_Union_of_Subrings_is_Subring  Thanks.

Comment: How do you know that the "candidate" is not equal with the whole ring?

Comment: @user119598 Good catch! Indeed, the family $F$ should be defined as _proper_ subrings of $R$.

Comment: Dear @rghthndsd, even so there is no guarantee that the union is not equal with $R$.

Comment: @120579: Yes, you are certainly correct. I have edited my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

A general example of an infinite commutative ring R with arbitrary infinite cardinal number $\alpha$ that has no maximal subring (and therefore each proper subring of R can not embedd in a maximal one)  : first note that if A is a ring and M is an A-module then the A-subalgebra of the idealization R=A(+)M has the form S=A(+)N where N is an A- submodule of M, in particular S is maximal if and only if N is maximal. Now let A be the ring of integer and M be a field of zero characteristic with cardinality $\alpha$,  then R has the same cardinality and it is well-known that M has no maximal A-submodule, hence R has no maximal subrings (note, subring means a unitrary subrings, i.e., has a same identity as R which is not zero, clearly in this case each subring of R contains A and hence is an A-algebra).